# Apollo graphql service on AWS Lambda Cannot read property 'Accept' of null

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-iam, aws-serverless

Apollo graphql service on AWS Lambda Cannot read property 'Accept' of null

```
{
"errorType": "TypeError",
"errorMessage": "Cannot read property 'content-type' of undefined",
"stack": [
    "TypeError: Cannot read property 'content-type' of undefined",
    "    at fileUploadHandler (/var/task/node_modules/apollo-server-lambda/dist/ApolloServer.js:144:50)",
    "    at Runtime.handler (/var/task/node_modules/apollo-server-lambda/dist/ApolloServer.js:167:13)",
    "    at Runtime.handleOnce (/var/runtime/Runtime.js:66:25)"
]
```

}

Comment: Dd you ever figure this out?  I'm hitting this as well

Comment: @MichaelCampbell I figured it out. Look in answers.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this has to do with the test that you are sending to AWS Lambda. You are sending the default request most likely as when I did that I got the same error. Try testing your application using apollo client.

Answer (score 0):

There is a breaking change in the apollo server. You need to write the file uploads line.
https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-server/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md#v230